# Python Indentation Error, but there is no actual error?

Tags: indentation

Not really sure why I keep getting this error:
[Indentation Error Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBAd0.png)

Everything is spaced out by 4 spaces (or 1 tab). When I change this one function to 5 spaces, it fixes the problem, but then creates new problems in 2 other methods. Could someone help me out here?

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces? If so, try using just tabs or just spaces and see if the problem persists

Comment: i know what the problem is, you probably copy pasted this from somewhere. just delete the space and manually add it again

Comment: No, I am not mixing tabs and spaces unfortunately... I wish that was the problem. I did copy and paste this from somewhere. I'll try and figure out if that is the problem